# relocation R_X86_64_32S against `_Py_NotImplementedStruct' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

Tags: python, centos7, caffe, pycaffe

I got this error message after run it on Centos 7 (512MB).

```
sudo make pycaffe
```

or

```
sudo make distribute
```

Error message

```
CXX/LD -o python/caffe/_caffe.so python/caffe/_caffe.cpp
/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a(abstract.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `_Py_NotImplementedStruct' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [python/caffe/_caffe.so] Error 1
```

Comment: Did you solve it? I'm getting the same error with matplotlib.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with trying to install dlib. The solution was to build Python with the `--enable-shared` flag. When using `pyenv` it can be done like this:

`PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--enable-shared" pyenv install --force 2.7.11`

Answer (score 0):

I had recently encountered a similar error with another software package.

Try passing `CFLAGS="-fPIC"` or `CXXFLAGS="-fPIC"` while configuring or building. That worked for me.

You might also want to go through [this page on `-fPIC` errors](https://web.archive.org/web/20150319085301/http://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/base/amd64/howtos/index.xml?part=1&chap=3):